# Theory T of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

Consider the theory $T$ of graphs. How can I show that there is no theory $T' \supseteq T$ such that the models of $T'$ are exactly the connected graphs (i.e. the graphs for which for every pair of vertices there exists a path between them)?

Comment: Okay and what's your question?

Comment: HINT: For vertices $u$ and $v$ and $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a sentence that says that there is no path of length $n$ between $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key fact is the *compactness theorem*: if $\Gamma$ is a collection of sentences, and every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model, then $\Gamma$ has a model.

Suppose $T'$ characterized the connected graphs. Consider the expansion of the language of graphs by two new constant symbols, $c, d$. Now let $\Gamma$ be $T'$ together with the sentences "there is no path of length $n$ connecting $c$ and $d$" for each $n$ (do you see why each such sentence is, in fact, expressible as a first-order sentence in the expanded language?).

Every finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model (why?), so by compactness so does $\Gamma$. But can any model of $\Gamma$ be connected? (Think about $c$ and $d$ . . .)

So there's a model $M$ of $\Gamma$ which is undirected. But $M$ is also a model of $T'$, since $T'\subseteq \Gamma$ . . .

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T'$ is such a theory. Let $T''$ be the set of all sentences which are true in every cycle graph $C_n.$ Since the graphs $C_n$ are connected, they are models of $T',$ so we have $T'\subseteq T''.$ Since $T''$ has arbitrarily large finite models, by the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) $T''$ has an uncountable model $G,$ and $G$ is not connected. (Why not?) Since $G$ is also a model of $T,$ this contradicts the assumption that all models of $T'$ are connected. Moreover, $T''$ also has a countable model which is not connected. (Why?)

Comment: While this does work, I think this isn't a great approach: the upwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem is basically just compactness, and there's a more direct attack via compactness that doesn't involve uncountable models *or* cycle graphs.

Comment: @NoahSchweber IMVHO the best approach is to show that $P_\infty$ (a two-way infinite path) is elementarily equivalent to $2P_\infty$ using Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games. But IANAL so what do I know.